# Python regex: return the whole sentence with a certain word in it from period to period

Tags: python, regex, text-analysis

Below is the sentence I want to process. It consists of IDs which start with two hashes at the front (`##2312435`) plus remaining text. I need a regular expression that would find sentences with word `likely` in them and would retrieve the whole sentence plus the ID.

Sentence:

> ##2312435 Jon is not home. John is likely to come home after midnight. Another not related sentence. ##2233442 Mark is very angry. Mark is likely to have a beer tonight.

I managed to write this:

```
(?=.\*((?<=##)\d+))(?=.*([^.]+(likely)+[^.]+))
```

but that does not retrieve the full sentence.

Expected result would look like: 2312435 John is likely to come home after midnight, 2233442 Mark is likely to have a beer tonight

I am asking this just for general knowledge, because I am struggling to get in grip with lookarounds. I already solved this without regex, but I thought I could give it a go and try to retrieve the needed info using regex. Thanks

Comment: you do realise you dont need regex for the whole thing?

Comment: Yes I do realise, I did it already without them, but I wanted to have a practise with regex and could not solve this one.

Comment: Ok. might want to add that in your post, and please add what you expect your regex to retrieve (Example)

Comment: There can occur multiple sentences after `##` with `likely` and the id is in a sentence itself. You want the `##`id and each of those sentences, or first only?

Comment: Each of them, thanks.

Comment: Maybe can be done with Python [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) by use of variable length lookbehind or [`\G` anchor like in this try (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/bH5sD7/2) but probably there are better solutions. Another problem that was not mentioned at all is the natural language parsing of a sentence.

Answer (score 2):

So it's very ugly, and works only in case if there only one sentence with word `likely`:

```
re.findall(r'##(\d+)(?:[^#]*\.)*([^#.]*?likely[^#.]*?)\.', text, re.IGNORECASE)

# Output:
#[('2312435', ' John is likely to come home after midnight'),
# ('2233442', ' Mark is likely to have a beer tonight')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
p = re.compile(r'^##\d+.*likely.*$')
res = p.match(t).group().replace('##','')
```

For example,

```
>>> t = '##2312435 Jon is not home. John is likely to come home after midnight. Another not related sentence. ##2233442 Mark is very angry. Mark is likely to have a beer tonight.'
>>> p = re.compile(r'^##\d+.*likely.*$')
>>> res = p.match(t).group().replace('##','')
>>> print res
2312435 Jon is not home. John is likely to come home after midnight. Another not related sentence. 2233442 Mark is very angry. Mark is likely to have a beer tonight.
```

Answer (score 0):

Any regex for this task will look ugly, but we can make it at least efficient.

The basic regex is to match the `##` + digits, capture these digits, then match any text that is not `##` + digit, then `likely`, then again any text that is not `##` + digit.

```
##(\d+)\s*((?:(?!##\d).)*\blikely\b(?:(?!##\d).)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV4aT5/1). The `(?:(?!##\d).)*` is a tempered greedy token that is rather heavy for the regex engine.

We can unroll it to increase performance like:

```
##(\d+)\s*([^#]*(?:#(?!#\d)[^#]*)*\blikely\b[^#]*(?:#(?!#\d)[^#]*)*)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/sV4aT5/2)

This is still not that efficient, and if you do not need to check for a whole word `likely`, you can use

```
##(\d+)\s*([^#l]*(?:#(?!#\d)[^l#]*|l(?!ikely)[^l#]*)*likely[^#]*(?:#(?!#\d)[^#]*)*)
```

See yet [another regex](https://regex101.com/r/sV4aT5/3).